How to say an object has multiple colors
I know most colors work as の adjectives except for the 6 principal colors that work as い adjectives. If I were to describe, say, a flag, which has 3 different colors on it, could I just string the colors with くて or で? For example:

イタリアの国旗は緑で白くて赤いです

It sounds a little weird to me specially since 緑 is a の adjective and 白い and 赤い are い adjectives. I also wonder if saying it that way implies that it's a "greenish-whiteish-red flag" or something like that. I would like to know what would be the most natural way to describe said thing. Thanks in advance.

I know you're asking how to list each colour, but if you just want to say "multi-coloured", it is [多彩]{た・さい}.

@istrasci 多彩 usually means "varied" or "diverse" rather than "multicolored".

Phrases like 大きくて赤い or 緑で軽くて長い are fine, but 緑で白くて赤い sounds contradictory and puzzling because it implies something is green, white, and red simultaneously.
Instead, you can say:

イタリアの国旗には緑と白と赤があります。 (simplest)
イタリアの国旗は緑と白と赤で出来ています。
イタリアの国旗は緑と白と赤で構成されています。 (formal)
イタリアの国旗は緑と白と赤の縞模様です。 (includes information about the pattern)

Here, 緑, 白 and 赤 are treated as nouns. You can just remove い (or の) to make the noun version of a color.
